Problem with server sync concerning a 2d ball physics unity photon
I'm encountering an issue with the synchronization of a bouncing ball in my Unity scene using Photon Transform View and Photon Rigidbody View . Despite implementing latency compensation, the ball's position update frequency seems to be insufficient. While the ball moves smoothly, it rarely touches the ground, indicating that its position is not being updated frequently enough.
I've tried adjusting the synchronization interval and optimizing the synchronization process, but the issue persists. Additionally, I've considered implementing client-side prediction to reduce perceived latency, but I'm unsure how to proceed. I also think that the ball's movements are actually too fast for the server to catch.
Any suggestions on how to improve the position update frequency of the bouncing ball while maintaining smooth gameplay in a multiplayer environment would be greatly appreciated.
